# Understanding the temporal difference prediction error formula which uses a derivative

Tags: reinforcement-learning, actor-critic

I'm very new to understanding the concept of prediction error underlying the output of the critic in the critic-actor method (RL learning), so bear with me, please.

For the temporal difference prediction error, we calculate $\delta$ (delta), otherwise known as the difference between reward predictions in consecutive states.

I'm slightly confused with this particular expression of the $\delta$ formula below:

$$\delta(t) = r(t) - \frac{1}{\tau} V(x(t)) + \frac{d V(x(t))}{d t}$$

Why is the third term after the equal-sign, $\frac{d V(x(t))}{d t}$, a derivative of the value of a state? Does this represent the value of a future state or past state?

I've also encountered this other formula: $\delta(t) = r(S_t) + V(S_t) − V(S_{t−1})$, and I'm trying to reconcile the two.

Is the temporal difference (TD) prediction error calculated by comparing the value of the present and past states, or present and future states?

Different articles are saying different things, and I'd like to hear others's opinions on this matter.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I just wanted to confirm that reinforcement learning is well within the scope of our site, as well as that of https://ai.stackexchange.com; despite the impression that may have been given by a now-deleted comment.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Derivative represents change in value of states, but considers the value at state(t+1) to calculate a delta that expresses this difference.

Comment: Doya, K. (1995). Temporal Difference Learning in Continuous Time and Space. Equation (5)... So if I'm interpreting correctly, the derivative represents a change in value between consecutive states. Doya says the temporal difference module follows a consistency rule where the change in value going from one state to the next equals the current value of a state minus the reward of a current state. Maybe somebody could clarify in case I'm not entirely right in saying this.